# Did that kid rapper "Lil' Bow Wow" really not release his iconic "That's My Name" song in the mid-1990s?

Tags: identify-this-song, history, similar-artists, rap, hip-hop

I have a distinct memory of myself hearing this song on the radio in a certain rented "summer house" in the (roughly) mid-1990s, perhaps even earlier, with the memorable refrain going:

> Bow wow wow, yippie yo, yippie yay

Song:

But when I now look it up on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bow_Wow_(That%27s_My_Name)

> Released  October 17, 2000

Huh? In the year 2000, I know for a fact that we had not had anything to do with that rented summer house for years already, so I could not possibly have heard it on the radio in the year 2000 (and *late* 2000, nonetheless)... And I remember myself still being a kid -- not 15 as I would've been in 2000.

While this wouldn't be the first time in my life that I got two different memories mixed up in my head, I really did think that this one was real. I expected to see something like:

> Released  August 15, 1995

Or even:

> Released  July 9, 1993

This disturbs me on a fundamental level. Could it be that I'm confusing this with some other kid rapper who also called himself "bow wow"? I know I'm really stretching it here, but I really did think that I had heard it in that room, sitting in a certain position and looking out into the kitchen from the bed. I strongly associate that song with that room, yet I apparently heard it many years later, at a much later age. It just doesn't add up.

It seems like I cannot trust my memories whatsoever. This one in particular downright *scares* me.

I notice that he raps "my name is" in a way which reminds me of a song by Eminem. This is the only hint I have that maybe this is a different/later song which parodies some earlier kid rapper, but I frankly don't think this is the explanation. I probably have just blended together two different memories...

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you heard George Clinton/P-Funk's "[Atomic Dog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyAEUWJlk1Q)" (1982), which first introduced the "Bow wow wow" line. It also could have been Public Announcement's "[D.O.G. in Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAwICu1RiLE)" (1998), which also used the line at the end of the track (and was [sued by the P-Funk "Atomic Dog"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_Dog#Copyright_lawsuit) copyright holders).

"Atomic Dog", according to Wikipedia (link above), was used in *Fresh Prince of Bel-Air* (1990-1996), *Boomerang* (1992), and *Menace II Society* (1993), so may well have received airplay around those times.

Another possibility is "[Who Am I (What's My Name)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2soGJXQAQec&t=2m37s)?" from Snoop Dogg's *Doggystyle* (1993).

George Clinton did a [remix of "Atomic Dog"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioqGEwPUrMs) with Coolio and Shorty in 1996.

WhoSampled.com [lists 318 songs](https://www.whosampled.com/George-Clinton/Atomic-Dog/sampled/?ob=0) that samples various elements of "Atomic Dog", 107 of which were released between 1993 and 1995.

Answer (score 2):

As @Aaron mentioned, you're almost certainly thinking of Snoop Dogg's 1993 hit, "What's My Name?". Snoop was Lil Bow Wow's early mentor --he was even the one who gave him his stage name (as an echo of his own). The Bow Wow track is essentially a reworking of Snoop's song, and Snoop himself appears on it, so it is easy to get the two tracks confused.